# Install of Lubuntu successful on second partition of HDD, but initramfs terminal opens and I am unable to type

Tags: boot, command-line, partitioning, 20.04, lubuntu

Along with the potentially relevant `Problem blacklisting hash (-13)` that appears several times, Lubuntu opens a terminal.

```
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
<...>
(initramfs) _
```

The ellipses are an omitted help line.
The underscore is where I should be able to enter commands but my keyboard does not respond. Nothing is wrong with the keyboard.
`fsck -f /dev/sda1` has no errors

Comment: FYI:  Please don't forget Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop/Server/Cloud/.. has five years of standard support; *flavors* like Lubuntu however only came with 3; thus are now EOL.  Refer https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-20-04-lts-end-of-life-and-current-support-statuses/ for Lubuntu.  You're still on-topic here as a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS System, but Lubuntu support has ended.

Comment: I'm trying the same thing with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but I am having the same issue.